# Sharing state between KStream applications in same consumer group with globalStateStore

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, apache-kafka-streams, stateful

The current problem I am trying to solve is about sharing states between multiple applications in the same consumer group, they consume data from the same topic but different partition.

So I have an inputTopic with say 3 partitions. I will be running 3 KStream microservices (eg: MS1, MS2, MS3) of each partition, each microservice will process and the write result to an output topic.

Problem: most of the time the microservice can operate independently within its partition, but there are cases a microservice will need to pull the previous state of an attribute before it is able to process, and this state might previously be processed and stored by another microservice.

So an example would be if I have data of a guy walking on 3 section of a road. Each section represents a partition. So if this guy walk from section 1 to section 2, we are no longer publishing his state from section 1 publisher. His state is now published by section 2 publisher. And if I have a microservice to process his data per section. When I see records coming to section 2, I need to check if the guy's previous state whether he just started walking on my section or is he coming to my section from another section in order for me to continue process his data.

Proposed solution: I have been reading about globalStateStore, and it seems like it might solve my problem. So I will write down my thinking here and some questions, just wondering if you can see any problems in my approach:

- Have the microservices read input topic from its assigned partition.
- Have a GlobalStateStore to store the state so all 3 microservices can read it.
- Since you can not write directly into the globalStateStore, I might have to create an intermediate topic to store the state (eg: <BobLocation,Long>; <BobMood,String>). The global state store will be created from this topic ("global-topic") - Is this correct?
- Then everytime my microservice get a message I will always read the globalStateStore to update its state then process the record - Do I read it as a GlobalKTable?
- Then update the state to the "global-topic"

Is there any implication on the restart process? As I am storing the state from the global state store all the time is there a problem when one app dies and the other one takes over?

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: A few things to consider:
1. If it is important for you that a specific instance of a microservice instance should process a given partition, then relying on the consumer group will not work as when one of the service goes down, then a rebalance will occur and result in 2 instances processing 3 partitions. It would be better to put the section number as part of the message.
2. Yes, Global State store would work for you. And it will be replicated on each instance of the microservice (sourced from the *global-topic*)

Comment: @bchu1392, Global State store should not be "too big". If you will keep there all message from input topic, that is splitted into several partition it might be too big. Maybe consider different way (key) off splitting the messages